# How can I get a plot with errorbars in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a set of data held in a dataframe, with another dataframe with the associated errors.  I would want to plot this with seaborn, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.  I can get a scatterplot, but not with errorbars.

I would want something like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDVfy.jpg)

Which was produced with Matplotlib.  Although if I can't plot the lines that is ok as well.  I am able to get a basic scatterplot with the `sns.scatterplot()` method, but can't find any way to add the errorbars to it.  Does anyone know how to do this in seaborn?

Thanks

Comment: why does it need to be seaborn?  If it's not incredibly difficult in matplotlib, isn't it better to stick with that?

Comment: @EMiller The data that I produced the example with was in the form of a numpy array. For some reason when I try to use the same method with a dataframe, it connects the points with a line (not a fit line, just a line connecting each point) which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a code snippet that generates the Matplotlib code that's not right?  That way people could either help you by fixing the matplotlib code, or by suggesting some other package to create the plot that you're looking for.